# Javascript works but jQuery doesn't and I have loaded the libraries

Tags: javascript, jquery

For some reason jQuery functions are not being called. If I `window.alert` out of any jQuery function, it works. I don't know what I am doing wrong.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Bubble Sort</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.9/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" type="text/css" media="all" />
    <script type="text/javascript" src="script.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.9/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>Bubble Sort</h1>
    <h2>Author: Hugo L. Villalobos</h2>
    <div></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  window.alert("Hello Wold");
})
```

Comment: Any errors in your console?

Comment: Assuming your code is in `script.js` you're including it in the wrong place - it needs to go ***after*** you include jQuery.js

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @Rory McCrossan said, script.js (or anything that includes jQuery code) should be included after the jQuery link. Change your code to:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Bubble Sort</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.9/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" type="text/css" media="all" />
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.9/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="script.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>Bubble Sort</h1>
    <h2>Author: Hugo L. Villalobos</h2>
    <div></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

This should make you right as rain. I just put the `script.js` after the jQuery API link.

Comment: what old libraries? 3.2.1 is pretty current

Comment: 3.2.1 is very current, but I noticed he had 1.8.9 also linked. I never meant to say that 3.2.1 was outdated, but I probably should've specified. I only left 1.8.9 in because I thought it was possible that he it still using old methods that were only accessible in 1.8.9 (which wouldn't be wise, the old methods are removed/deprecated for a reason).

Comment: it's jQueryUI, not jQuery.

Comment: Wow, I'm shaking my head. I'm not really sure how I missed that. My bad, Jeremy Thille. I'll remove the mention of outdated libraries from my post. -_-